# Maven Dependency Tree - Some dependencies of Spring use old version

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, dependencies

I do not have so much experience with Maven (I apologies in advance, if you will find the following scenario trivial). In POM.xml, I specified Spring version:

```
<properties>
...
    <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

and then, I use it for all the Spring dependencies:

```
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

But when I execute: `mvn dependency:tree`, I can see that some dependencies (for example: spring-core) use old version numbers. Can you explain this please.

```
Tracking admin$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Tracking 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:tree (default-cli) @ Tracking ---
[INFO] com.mycompany:Tracking:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.0.RC3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc-portlet:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-alpha-5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.200 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-26T18:02:17+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tracking admin$
```

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml? (also if there exists some  parent pom, it could be useful as well)

Comment: Hi @Asettouf  ... I think i found the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952603/maven-downloads-spring-aop-3-0-0-rc3-instead-of-3-1-1-final . Apparently, when I created the Restful Web Services, it generated a Java file which used the Jersey Import. If I comment the Jersey dependencies in Maven, I notice that spring core uses the correct version number. Many thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven downloads Spring-AOP 3.0.0.RC3 instead of 3.1.1.Final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952603/maven-downloads-spring-aop-3-0-0-rc3-instead-of-3-1-1-final)

Comment: @StefanCiprianHotoleanu you can pull the post down(delete it) if you own it and you get to know that it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use artifacts with version matching `${spring.version}`, you need to provide core dependencies manually. Some Spring dependencies use artifacts with older versions.

Also useful thing is dependency exclusion which you can use here to say strictly to Maven that you don't want to use specific dependency from other dependencies.

Example of exclusion:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-something</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>sample.spring</groupId> <!-- exclude spring-other from spring-something -->
          <artifactId>spring-other</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```